# Error 500, when I try to launch a new server with JupyterHub

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I have a Linux machine without Internet access where I install JupyterHub from the whl files downloaded from Pypi. This method worked fine when I had Python 3.6, but now I have installed Python 3.9 and I have the following issue.

The installation of all the libraries where correct, and I can launch jupyterhub (and jupyterlab) without any issue. For launching jupyterhub I use the next command (executed as root):

`/opt/python/bin/jupyterhub -f /home/userTest/jupyterhub_config_global.py`

The, I open the jupyterlab page in the Navigator and I log in, it also works fine. When the user is logged, I can launch the server for that user but then it fails with an error 500.

When I see the Jupyterhub logs, the first error that occurs after launching the server is the following:

`error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.9.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

After that error, I receive more error but I suppose that are caused because of this first error.

Searching on Internet, I see the approach of modifying the config file used in the launch of jupyterhub with the next lines:

```
c.Spawner.env.update('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
c.Spawner.env_keep.append('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

and I also tried the following solution:

```
c.Spawner.env_keep = ['PATH', 'PYTHONPATH', 'CONDA_ROOT', 'CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV', 'VIRTUAL_ENV', 'LANG', 'LC_ALL', 'JUPYTERHUB_SINGLEUSER_APP', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH']
```

But it did not work. I know the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is pointing to the folder when the objectlibpython3.9.so.1.0  is located. But it seems that is not passed correctly in the moment the spawner is invoked.